# GtkFileChooser choose only directories

Tags: gtk, gtk3

How can I make a [GtkFileChooserDialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) which choose only directories / folders? I have never used the gtk api before, I just need a quick dialog for choosing a directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`gtk_file_chooser_set_action()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-set-action) function of the `GtkFileChooser` interface, which is implemented by `GtkFileChooserDialog` and `GtkFileChooserWidget`.

The [`GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SELECT_FOLDER`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#GtkFileChooserAction) enumeration value allows you to select folders, instead of files.